# SQL Select query returning unwanted data

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have a table that is populated with data from a query that selects studentid numbers from a database. the view is like so :

[image: Pic]

As you can see the same piece of data is being output multiple times. I have a feature that for any reason a counselor can not finish a student then they can send the student to another counselor. Now to maintain historic data I keep all that data. Now when I go back to my student que then it shows all the current data (which I want) and all the past historic data (which I dont want)

this is my sql statement :

```
    try 
                {
            $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT 
        session.session_id AS id, 
        session.anum, 
        student.first, 
        student.last, 
        session.why, 
        session.studentcomments, 
        session.aidyear,
        support.counselorcomments 
        FROM 
        student INNER JOIN session ON student.anum = session.anum 
        INNER JOIN session_status ON session.status = session_status.status 
        LEFT JOIN support ON session.session_id = support.session_id
        WHERE session.status = 0 OR session.status = 2");

    $query->execute();
            $result = $query->fetchall();
                }
                    catch (PDOException $e) {
                    error_log($e->getMessage());
                    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Now the way I have my database set up is how I want to keep it as it works. I just think the way I am querying the data is what the problem is.

this is a picture of the data in mysql :

[image]

**EDIT**

Now since that problem is fixed now I am having an error that when ever a insert happens (updating the support.starttime timestamp) the above record disappears this is my updated sql

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT session.session_id AS id, session.anum, student.first, student.last, session.why, 
                        session.studentcomments, session.aidyear, support.counselorcomments FROM student LEFT JOIN 
                        session ON student.anum = session.anum LEFT JOIN session_status ON 
                        session.status = session_status.status LEFT JOIN support ON session.session_id = support.session_id
                        WHERE (session.status) IN (0) OR (session.status) IN (2) 
                        AND support.starttime = (SELECT MAX(support.starttime) FROM support INNER JOIN session ON session.session_id = 
                        support.session_id)");
```

Comment: you have one to many relationship so join is fetching multiple results and therefore your records are being repeated

Comment: Is there a way around this so that I can just show a specific view of the most current record in the support table?

Comment: well i dont know what you are trying to do but take a look at GROUP_CONCAT of mysql this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    session.session_id as id,
    session.anum,
    student.first,
    student.last,
    session.why,
    session.studentcomments,
    session.aidyear,
    support.counselorcomments
FROM student
        INNER JOIN session 
            ON student.anum = session.anum
        LEFT JOIN support 
            ON session.session_id = support.session_id
        WHERE session.status IN (0,2)
```

Used DISTINCT as ALberto told me to do! Thank you alberto

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you only want the most current row from the Session table, correct?

If so, you will want to implement a sub-select in your Where clause to grab the MAX(session.starttime).

If this is the case, you can use the following syntax:

```
WHERE ...(what you already have)...
  AND session.startime = (SELECT MAX({YourTable}.starttime)
                            FROM {YourTable}
                           WHERE {YourTable}.anum = session.anum)
```

If I had the details of all the tables involved, I would write the entire query for you.  Does this answer your question?

Update answer:

You must tell the subquery which session_id you want the starttime for, you do this by joining your subquery table with your main query resultset.

Your subquery should be:

(SELECT MAX(a.starttime)
   FROM support a
  WHERE a.session_id = session.session_id)

Comment: you sir are awesome!!! all I added was : AND support.starttime = (SELECT MAX(support.starttime) FROM support) and that did it, didn't even need the where. I will update the OP.

Comment: also doing the ORDER BY for some reason didn't order all the rows. It chose specific rows to choose. Wow I really need to get a solid understanding of sub queries. All in all a sub query can be used to more specifically choose the data you want, correct?

Comment: Thank you, and a subquery is to limit the data returned, yes -- *but*, you need to tie your subquery back to your original query & student ID; otherwise, you are returning the most recent row for *any* student (a cartesian product)!  :)

Comment: I'm still working on it, recognition will be given, let me just work with it.

Comment: Yes I am having the error that when ever a new timestamp is entered then the above record gets removed. I updated my query on the OP

Comment: In your subquery, for tables that are also in your main query, insure that you are using any WHERE-CLAUSE statements and JOINS from the main query.  You have to insure that your main query criteria are being used in your subquery for tables in both queries.  For instance, in your main query you use `session.status in (0,2)` but you are not using that in your subquery.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Sorry for being bothersome just never had to use sub queries before and that lack of experience is causing me a lot of grief.